# Page content loads inconsistently without developer tools (F12) open in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser-cache

Puzzling me is (probably this is a hint to solve), the page loads consistently with the developer tools open. This is in Chrome. I do see a console error:

```
Uncaught Syntax Error: missing ) after argument list
```

Could a syntax error as seen above cause an inconsistent behavior? Or what else could trigger such a behavior. I am OK with sharing more info as needed.

Comment: run your code through a linting tool...it will show you exactly where the problem is

Comment: Maybe with developer tool open, there is some time lag in code execution and that is altering the code execution sequence. If you have timer/events in your code.It is quiet possible. Behind every weird behavior there is a valid logical explanation :)

Comment: are you sure it never works when devtools is closed? it sounds random, just that you can see it when devtools is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that there were two different versions of jQuery loaded. After removing one of them my issue was resolved.